# Why does my Javascript/JQuery work on my local machine but not on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, animation, css-animations

I have made my own webpage. I bootstraped animation on my page through Javascript / Jquery and it works on my local machine. When I FTP'ed the code to the server, and load the page, the animation does not appear.

Any ideas?

The animation portion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

          $('#midground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
          $('#foreground').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});
          $('#background').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});

            $('#midground').animate({
                backgroundPosition:"(0px 20000px)"
            }, 240000, 'linear');

            $('#foreground').animate({
                backgroundPosition:"(0px 20000px)"
            }, 120000, 'linear');

            $('#background').animate({
                backgroundPosition:"(0px 20000px)"
            }, 480000, 'linear');

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The answer lies in your browser's error console. Use it.

Comment: Simple `GET http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~szhu1234/js/jquery.backgroundposition.js 404 (Not Found)`  You missed to add this file.  Check the folder path and make sure you have uploaded it in server

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a javascript file on the page that has not been loaded onto the server.

```
 {path}/js/jquery.backgroundposition.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference a JavaScript file which is not loaded / found on the server

(server_name) / (path_required) / jquery.backgroundposition.js